# Irreducible representations of $A_5$

Tags: representation-theory

This is an exercise problem in Artin's "Algebra" (Cp.10 Q6.7):

- The group $S_5$ operates by conjugation on its normal subgroup $A_5$. How does this action operate on the isomorphism classes of irreducible representations of $A_5$?

My approach is that we consider this action operates on the conjugacy classes of $A_5$, then no isomorphism classes will permute, so it is a trivial action operates on those isomorphism classes. Is this right, while I think it is a bit confused.

Comment: The action does not quite preserve the conjugacy classes, since some of the $S_5$ classes have split into two when considered as classes for $A_5$.

Comment: Besides, I know there are only five irreducible representations of A5, doesn't it related?